# How to make the size of a glyph "fixed" in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

When I plot a circle like for example:
`myPlot.circle(0, 0, line_width=0.5, size=6, line_color="green", fill_color=None)`
the size of 6 is not fixed. When I zoom out or in it stays the same. How can I bind the size to the x and y axis? So if my x and y axis is Meter my circle has a radius of 6 meter.

Answer (score 1):

`size` is always in screen (pixel) units. You need to set a `radius` which is in "data-space" units. Note you will probably also want to set `match_aspect=True` and use default auto-ranges on the figure, to make sure the radius has the same length in data-space on both axes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I couldn't find any solution sooner I "solved" this problem by using matplotlib. But I will keep this in mind for future projects!